# Migrate SAS disks from E200i to B320i Smart Array

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have an older HP ML350 G5 series server with 4 SAS 72GB hdds in RAID 0+1. It's down and beyond repair.

So I was wondering would it work if I was just to plug those in newer server with B320i RAID controller?

If not, is it at all possible to migrate those disks to newer server, or I must do complete re-install and data restore?

Regards

Comment: What type of server has the B320i controller in it?

Answer (score 4):

I hate when people say that the server is "down" or "crashed".

*What exactly is wrong with it?*

The HP Smart Array E200i controller appeared in HP ProLiant G5 servers from 2006-2008. The B320i controller is featured in low-end HP ProLiant *Gen8* servers, which were introduced in 2012.

The disks have different drive carriers and the controllers have different feature sets.

*G5 disk on left. Gen8 disk on right.*
[image]

Most-importantly, the B320i is a bit of a *fakeraid* controller versus the E200i being a real Smart Array controller, **so a completely different driver is needed for the OS**. In addition, most B320i deployments aren't capable of using SAS drives without an additional license.

The advice about moving disks in the other answer does not apply here.

You don't have a practical option here other than repairing your G5 server or getting a replacement unit. They're very inexpensive on eBay.

Comment: Valid point. I was presuming that B320i as compatible with E200i. Can you tell me what newer version RAID controller would accomodate my old disks?

Comment: A Smart Array P400 or P410 would be the best choices. Another E200i can also work. I don't know where you're located, but in the United States, a G5 ProLiant can be purchased for under $75.

Comment: I'm in Europe. Yeah, i know i could get them cheap, but it takes time to deliver. I figured it would be fastest if i could just buy a new one, plug the disks and everything could be ready in one day.

Answer (score 1):

HP's official statement on moving hard drive.

**Moving drives and arrays**
You can move drives to other ID positions on the same array controller. You can also move a complete array
from one controller to another, even if the controllers are on different servers.

Before moving drives, you must meet the following conditions:

• If moving the drives to a different server, be sure the new server has enough empty bays to
accommodate all the drives simultaneously.

• The array does not have failed or missing drives.

• No spare drive in the array is acting as a replacement for a failed drive.

• The controller is not performing capacity expansion, capacity extension, or RAID or stripe size
migration.

• The controller is using the latest firmware version.

• The server is powered down.

**Before you move an array to another controller, you must meet the following conditions:**

CAUTION: If the number of physical or logical drives exceeds the limit for the controller model
and firmware version, then the controller may recognize an unpredictable subset of the drives,
possibly resulting in failed arrays and data loss.

• If the other controller is connected already to one or more arrays of configured logical drives, the total
number of logical drives on the controller after the drives have been moved must not exceed the number
of logical drives that the controller supports. This number depends on the controller model and on the
controller firmware version.

• The total number of physical drives on the other controller after the drives have been moved must not
exceed the maximum number of supported physical drives for that controller model and firmware
version.

• All drives in the array must be moved at the same time.

When all the conditions have been met, move the drives:

1. Back up all data before removing any drives or changing configuration. This step is required if you are
   moving data-containing drives from a controller that does not have a cache module.
2. Power down the system.
3. Move the drives.
4. Power up the system.
5. Observe the POST messages:

o If a 1785 POST message appears, the drive array did not configure properly. Continue with step 6.

o If a 1724 or 1727 POST message appears, drive positions were changed successfully and the
configuration was updated. Continue with step 7.

6. If the array did not configure properly, do the following:

a. Power down the system immediately to prevent data loss.

b. Return the drives to their original locations.

c. Restore the data from backup, if necessary.

7. Verify the new drive configuration by running ORCA or ACU ("Configuration tools" on page 43).

From: http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01608507

Comment: None of this applies to this situation as the servers are THREE generations apart, while the controllers are TWO generations apart. Different drivers, and the B320i can't accommodate SAS disks without a license.

Comment: @ewwhite good point. maybe the op could get is hand on a e200 to plug into the new server or a p4xx serie. (or a working g5 from ebay)

Answer (score 1):

Full reinstall is IHMO safer option, Windows most probably will give you BSOD error 0x0000007B @ boot due:

- incorrect disk controller driver,
- lack of disk controller driver,

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324103

Full reinstall and full array sync is also better, because it'll help you verify the hardware - disks, memory and its stability.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of that, that's my last option. I estimate it would take mew at least 3 days to get where it was before crash.

Comment: Depending on software there may be an option to do repair install.

Comment: oracle database, oracle application server (forms & reports) and some other less important software. Think it could be done?

Comment: Yep, I did it many times. Repair install doesn't touch that kind of things. It'll touch (in short), basic system files and device drivers and some parts of Windows registry excluding software configuration.

Comment: can you explain general procedure?

Comment: No, unless you give us some info what's there (windows version details).

Comment: Windows server 2003, Oracle DB & Application 10g, that's how much I know

Comment: Then you need: raid with original OS, windows installation cd's with controller drivers (you can compile it using nlite) or floppy drive (it may be USB type) and floppy disk containing so called text drivers for raid controller, repair procedure is here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/325375

Comment: same procedure like when win xp crashes and you use repair option with installation cd?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: OK then, i've done it few times, i'll give it a try. Thanks.